# Why is my pygame program laggy even with a great pc and other code works fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Code to run the simple game.
All it does is move a circle just to test the fps
But when you run it, it takes awhile for it to start and than stutters

```
import pygame 
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

playerX = 250 # Player X
playerY = 250 # Player Y
playerColor = (10, 10, 100)


class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color

    def show(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y), 10)

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        playerX += 5
        player = Player(playerX, playerY, playerColor)

        screen.fill((60, 30, 10))
        player.show()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You need to update the position of the player and draw the scene in the application loop rather than the event loop.
Create the instance of the `Player` before the application loop:

```py
import pygame 
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color

    def show(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y), 10)

playerX = 250 # Player X
playerY = 250 # Player Y
playerColor = (10, 10, 100)
player = Player(playerX, playerY, playerColor)

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    #<--| INDENTATION 

    player.x += 5

    screen.fill((60, 30, 10))
    player.show()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Thank you, ive been struggling with this for awhile now.